# Other team members taking credit for my work

Tags: team, team-building

I am currently working on a project with another delivery manager. Set up is as follows

- Product owner who sets requirements
- 2 Delivery managers, myself and another (who works directly with product owner)
- UI/UX, agencies, copy team designers managed by her
- dev team managed by me

To cut a long story short:

- My team delivered project on time, when there were delays it was caused by bottlenecks from dependencies on her team not being addressed quickly enough
- Decided to dive deeper into JIRA, and could see from metrics that the other delivery manager is implementing Scrum in a poor way. Burndowns are never met, velocity is all over place. Average ticket completion time is over 5 days etc In contrast, my teams average issue completion time is 1 day

As part of closing down ceremony, presentation was done to my department, the slow delivery manager and my devs were given credit, my delivery plan and the role I played is not mentioned at all. In private I was told by product owner I was doing a great job, but I kind of felt she overlooked me when it mattered. Given that before the presentation they had a slide on the other delivery manager's delivery, I suggested to have a slide on my role in the delivery, but the product owner didn't want to do it saying that it is to low level.

I am in two minds of how to approach this, on one hand I am telling myself that I should not care as long as I get the job done but then on the other it is bothering me that I've not been acknowledged for my hard work. I am a new joiner, and want to build a reputation.

What do you think? Should I let it slide?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I'd let it go.. your team's work has been acknowledged and recognized by the PO and that's what counts. Making a stink about it not being presented on a slide during the presentation just comes across as petty points-scoring over the other delivery manager.

Comment: Fair enough, will do that.

Answer (score 0):

I would personally let it go, you got some kind of recognition from the product owner. She is definitely not overlooking you. Sometimes a "Well done" in private means more than a public "Well done".